# How to prevent a Delphi MDI application from showing the caption of the maximized child

Tags: delphi, mdi

how can I prevent a Delphi MDI application from showing the caption of the currently maximized MDI child in the caption of the MDI parent form?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

haven't had a chance to test this, but:

in the child OnResize, test for WindowState = wsMaximized.
If it is, then set Caption := ''
If not, set caption as required - you will need to need to remember this.

Comment: This does work when the child form gets maximized, but not when it gets restored. Some more tweaking is necessary, but the solution should get the OP started. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Tweaking Gerry's answer as mghie suggested:

```
private
  PreviousState: TWindowState;

procedure TMDIChildForm.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PreviousState = wsMaximized then
    Caption := 'Desired Caption'
  else if WindowState = wsMaximized then
    Caption := '';
  PreviousState := WindowState;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. MDI is outdated stuff, and support for it is deprecated (actually, it has been for years). The limitations probably won't ever be changed because of the deprecation.